# ffplay/lavfi: How to play dshow?

Tags: video, webcam

I am attempting to playback 3 x dshow devices (Logi Brio webcams) with the hstack filter. I can successfully playback local .mp4 files with the following command, but I'm struggling to bring the dshow devices into the mix.

Working code w/ local .mp4 videos:

```
ffplay -f lavfi "movie=video1.mp4[v0];movie=video2.mp4[v1];movie=video3.mp4[v2];[v0][v1][v2]hstack=inputs=3"
```

Error when attempting to connect to the dshow device via

```
ffplay -f lavfi "movie='Logitech BRIO':f=dshow":
```

*nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0

[dshow @ 0000000000000000] Malformed dshow input string.
[Parsed_movie_0 @ 0000000000000000] Failed to avformat_open_input 'Logitech BRIO'
[lavfi @ 0000000000000000] Error initializing filter 'movie' with args 'Logitech BRIO:f=dshow'
movie='Logitech BRIO':f=dshow: I/O error*

Same result with the 'Alternative name' for the BRIO. I'm just after a way to preview 3 x dshow devices stacked together with the hstack filter via ffplay and lavfi. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
ffplay -f lavfi "movie='video\=WebCam SC-0311139N':f=dshow"
```

Escaping the = is crucial.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).